# How to send an encoded password from Server to Email

Tags: java, email, encoding

on my app the user can demand a new password if he has forgotten his own.
He just need to put his Email adress and on the the server side a random password will be generated and encoded. 
This new random generated and encoded password will be send to his Email and saved in the DB.
For the sending email iam using JavaMail.

```
    Properties props = new Properties();
    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);

    try {
        Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);
        try {
            msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress("mymail@mail.com", "www.myApp.com"));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            return false;
        }
        try {
            msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                    new InternetAddress(userMail, username));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            return false;
        }

        // Betreff
        msg.setSubject( subject );
        System.out.println("subject: "+subject);
        // Hauptteil
        msg.setText(text);
        System.out.println("text: "+text);
        Transport.send(msg);

        return true;

    } catch (AddressException e) {
        return false;
    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        return false;
    }
```

but the password must apear decoded on the customers email.
Is there another way to send a encoded password to the customers mail?
How can the encoded password apear decoded on the customers email?
Please help.

Answer (score 1):

There a pair of thecniques you can use to this:

1. You can send an HTML message with text and rubbish in the form of html comments to allow the sending of the password and don't let to be completely readable by a machine.

For instance, if your password is "SECRET", you can send something like this:

```
S<!-- skdfjfak -->E<!-- 38 -->C<!-- d82vs -->R<!-- e38 -->E<!-- sjsk-->T
```

That would be perfectly visible and readable in an email program, but complete nonsense for a normal sniffer. However, using an HTML parser could strip the comments an get the password anyway.

2. You can compose an image with the password and send it attached to the pasword.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Do you know how to compose this kind of image with google app engine? Do you know any tutorial?

Comment: No, I have no idea of doing shuch thing with the google app engine, but I think that you can add other dependencies in the maven project, and therefore you can add some jar that generates images.

Comment: raul luna do you have any idea what kind of jar files i have to add?